# Using Formerly available versions of packages as dependencies

Tags: r, r-package, cran

Two days ago, one of the dependencies ([**depth**](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=depth)) of an R package that I maintain was archived on CRAN.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from CRAN, but can I formally depend on those older versions if I want to submit my package to CRAN? Or is only the newest, non-archived version of a package allowed to be listed as a dependency in the `DESCRIPTION` file? If I am restricted to non-archived packages, then is there anything I can do?

I tried looking for alternatives (packages that could replace **depth**, such as **DepthProc**) but all of them are too slow. I also tried contacting the maintainer of **depth**, but he hasn't replied yet.

Comment: Correction: The package was archived not removed.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [CRAN Repository Policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html):

> Orphaned CRAN packages should not be strict requirements (in the
> ‘Depends’, ‘Imports’ or ‘LinkingTo’ fields, including indirectly).
> They are allowed in ‘Suggests’ if used conditionally, although this is
> discouraged.

I assume CRAN is at least as strict with archived packages. Thus, I'd say you are out of luck if you want to submit your package to CRAN. You will need to find an alternative. Usually there is an issue with a package if it has been archived.